# How to get the import correct when creating protocol buffer?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, python-import, protoc

I am relatively new to protocol buffers and python, so I stumbled upon a problem described below. (I've done plenty of research in this issue, but found no solution)

The relevant hirarchy of my code:

```
.
└── MainFolder
    ├── main.py
    ├── create_python_proto.bat
    ├── protos
    │   └── foo.proto
    ├── client
    │   ├── protos
    │   │   ├ __init__.py
    │   │   ├ foo_pb2.py
    │   │   └ foo_pb2_grpc.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── client.py
    │   └── etc...
    └── server
        ├── ...
```

(main.py is my starting point)

When I create the code from my protobuf with protoc, the files are placed correctly, as I want them to be.
But the auto generated code inside of my 'foo_pb2_grpc.py' is not correct, precisly the import of 'foo_pb2.py'.

Actual state:

```
from protos import foo_pb2 as protos_dot_foo__pb2
```

Target state:

```
from ..protos import foo_pb2 as protos_dot_foo__pb2
```

I create the proto files via my 'create_python_proto.bat', command below:

```
setlocal

python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I . --python_out=.\client --grpc_python_out=.\client protos\foo.proto

endlocal
```

So when I run my program from 'main.py' I get an "ImportError" at 'foo_pb2_grpc.py' where it says:

> "cannot import name 'foo_pb2' from 'protos' (unknown location)"

What am I doing wrong? I am desperatly searching for a solution, but I just cannot find one...

Thanks for helping me out in advance!

ps: both '_ _ init _ _.py' given in '.\MainFolder\client' and '.\MainFolder\client\protos' are empty

Comment: To make the import work with the actual state without further modifications, just add the client directory to sys.path in your main.py

Comment: @Ronny I did this to temporary solve my problem. However adding something to sys.path manually seems like a bad habit for me. But I am not sure if avoiding sys.path.append at all costs is the way to go or just nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, using modules with `protoc`-generated Python is gnarly and best avoided.

The gRPC repo's [examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/41ec08c69a9d298015cb44316c445d58ad0b2e9c/examples/python) avoid using modules (possibly for this reason).

A solution is to:

- Create a true module source e.g. `src`
- Manually revise the `foo_pb2_grpc.py` import path
- Use absolute|relative `import` references

With:

```bash
src
├── client
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
├── __init__.py
├── protos
│   ├── foo_pb2_grpc.py
│   ├── foo_pb2.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── server
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main.py
```

And:

```bash
python \
-m grpc_tools.protoc \
--proto_path ${PWD}/protos \
--python_out=${PWD}/src/protos \
--grpc_python_out=${PWD}/src/protos \
${PWD}/protos/foo.proto
```

And `src/protos/foo_pb2_grpc.py`:

```py
from ..protos import foo_pb2 as foo__pb2
```

Or:

```py
import src.protos.foo_pb2 as foo__pb2
```

And e.g. `src/server/main.py`:

```py
from ..protos import foo_pb2
from ..protos import foo_pb2_grpc
```

Or `from src.protos import ...`

**NOTE** The `protoc`-generated packages represent the interface between peers (client|server). If these were provided by a 3rd-party, the generated files would be in an entirely distinct module (`com.third.party`). You may wish to follow a similiar practice for in-house protos. At least, place these alongside (as here `src.protos`) client and server implementations of them.